# Select query that creates a table of monthly incremental entries

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to be able to use a select query that will somehow generate a list of entries consisting of monthly increments from two variables STARTDATE and ENDDATE. An example would look like this:

Getting the STARTDATE and ENDDATE from the table

```
STARTDATE   ENDDATE
----------- -----------
01-JAN-2011 1-DEC-2011
```

which results into

```
CALENDAR 
--------- 
01-JAN-11 
01-FEB-11 
01-MAR-11 
01-APR-11 
01-MAY-11 
01-JUN-11 
01-JUL-11 
01-AUG-11 
01-SEP-11 
01-OCT-11 
01-NOV-11 
01-DEC-11
```

Any ideas on how to doing this? Someone told me about a method called 'CONNECT BY' but it doesn't work with leap year or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select date '2011-01-01' start_date,
  3           date '2011-12-01' end_date
  4      from dual
  5  )
  6  select add_months( start_date, level-1 )
  7    from x
  8* connect by level <= months_between( end_date, start_date ) + 1
SQL> /

ADD_MONTH
---------
01-JAN-11
01-FEB-11
01-MAR-11
01-APR-11
01-MAY-11
01-JUN-11
01-JUL-11
01-AUG-11
01-SEP-11
01-OCT-11
01-NOV-11
01-DEC-11

12 rows selected.
```